# ffmpeg crashes when trying to convert for HTML5

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I am trying following command to convert my ogv file to webm

```
"C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-git-6c4e9ca-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Users\myusername\Videos\Miro\Converted\hm3.ogv" -b 1500k -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -f webm    -g 30 -s 640x360 "C:\Users\myusername\Videos\Miro\Converted\hm3.ogv.webm"
```

I get a yellow warning message saying [ogg @ 0000000001A5FA40] Unknown skeleton version 4.0

and then ffmpeg crashes.

Does anyone knows what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the 32-bit version.